# What would you do if you wanted to put 3 icons in the navbar of an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mobile

I have an iOS app and I need to add 3 icons to the navbar, however, when the user scrolls the screen, the 3 icons take up so much room in the navbar that the page title (which would move to the top center of the navbar) gets truncated to only a few letters on an SE (320px width).

I also feel that 3 icons is too much for the navbar on iPhone and I have never seen it doe before.

Does anyone have a solution or example of a screen they have designed or have seen that deals with this dilemma?

I had thought about the ol' Ellipsis but Settings and Action Sheet shouldn't be inside an Ellipsis.
Thanks

### [image]

---

---

[image]

Comment: SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: Also wdym by "All icons are global to that screen"?

Comment: Aheze - Swift UI

Comment: "All icons are global to that screen" - meaning that the action of the icon relates to the screen as a whole. All 3 icons represent actions that, if used, would affect the whole screen and not just part of it. For example, I can't put the settings to the right of the Animals label, because the Calendar and Action Sheet icon have just as much importance to the screen as the Settings.

Comment: I must be dense. (That's okay, not the first time.) What's the actual issue? As I see it, you need to control the navigation bar? Or are you trying to deal with a master/detail UI where the hierarchy goes more than those two?

Comment: Additional. Is your target iOS 14? Have you looked into menus? Split view controllers?

Comment: dfd - sorry that was all my fault. I poorly wrote the question in a rush and have edited it now. Target is ios14 and 15 only. (when 15 is released.)

Comment: The fact that you "feel that 3 icons is too much for the navbar", and the idea of how others "deal with the dilemma" is really opinionated stuff.  This question is still too opinionated.  You get to define what is good or bad and you have to be able to clearly define what the answer to your question will look like.  If there are a wide variety of solutions, then we get into opinionated stuff.  Consider also https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of to fit all those buttons on the screen while preserving the nav bar title:

### **Floating corner button**

Great example of this is in the Outlook app as shown below:
[image: Outlook floating corner button]
Great code-along example at [Medium](https://medium.com/programming-with-swift/create-a-floating-action-button-with-swiftui-4d05dcddc365) if you want specifics on how to make that. Essentially a `ZStack` with a button and the rest of the view.

### **List Button**

I'm currently using this in my own app to free up some space in the nav bar:
[image: List Button]
The "Add new category" button is always the first item in the List view no matter what is in the list.

### **Nav Bar VStack Buttons**

Outlook also does something similar to this, but you can use a `VStack` inside of the `ToolbarItem` object to put buttons below the title of the nav bar like so:
[image: Nav Bar VStack Buttons]
This is done using the code below:

```
NavigationView {
    Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Title").font(.headline)
                    Button("Subtitle") {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

(copied from [surunw.com](https://sarunw.com/posts/custom-navigation-bar-title-view-in-swiftui/))

Other than your ellipsis option you say you're wanting to steer clear of, these three are the prominent ones I can think of.

Comment: Wow thank you for those ideas. I really like the idea of the VStack. I assume that is what Apple uses in the Contacts app for their quick action buttons.